# How to identify real red pixels?

Tags: c, colors

I'm wirtting a program that changes all the image pixels to grayscale except for the red ones. At first, i thought it would be easier, but I'm having trouble trying to find the best way to determine if a pixel is red or not.

The first method I tried was a formula: `Green < Red/2 && Blue < Red/1.5`

results:

[michael jordan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Wf2.png)

[goldhill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esBMo.png)

Michael Jordan's image shows some not red pixels that pass the formula, like #7F3222 and #B15432. So i tried a different method, `hue >= 345 || hue <= 9`, trying to limit only the red part of the color wheel.

results:

[michael jordan 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vscM7.png)

[goldhill 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h73ZJ.png)

Michael Jordan's image now has less not red pixels and goldhill's image has more red pixels than before but still not what I want.

My methods are incorrect or just some adjustments are missing? if they're incorrect, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the code.

Comment: "still not what I want"... we can't tell you what you want. What is a "red pixel" according to you?

Comment: You have the right idea looking at hue separately from saturation and brightness. The next step is to realize that your computer is looking at each pixel separately. A human, on the other hand, looks at pixels as part of a group, and assigns the same color to each pixel in that group (regardless of the actual color of the pixel). That makes it quite difficult for a computer to mimic the color perception of a human. The computer needs to identify boundaries between different color groups, and *then* assign a color to each pixel based on the predominant color in the group.

Comment: Expanding on above comment, you could possibly see if you get better results by not only looking at the current pixel, but also surrounding pixels. Make a pixel more likely to be counted as red if it has a lot of red neighbours.

Comment: Note: do not link external images: this is a reference site, so we want that question and images will always be available (we cannot guarantee with external sites). So just include them in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question "How to identify 'real' red pixels", begs the question "what a red pixel actually is, especially if it has to be 'real'".

The **RGB** (**r**ed, **g**reen, **b**lue) color model is not well suited to answer that question, therefore you should use the **HSV** (**h**ue, **s**aturation, **v**alue) model.

- **H**ue defines the color in degrees (0 - 360 degrees)
- **S**aturation defines the intensity of the color (0 - 100 %)
- **V**alue or Brightness defines the luminosity (0 - 100 %)

**Steps:**

- convert **RGB** to **HSV**
- if the **H** value is not red (+/- 30 degrees, you'll have to define a threshold range of what you consider to be red, 'real' red would be 0 degrees)

  - set **S** to 0 (zero), by doing so we remove the saturation of the color, which results in a gray shade
- leave the brightness (**V**) as it is (or play around with it and see how it effects the results)
- convert **HSV** to **RGB**

Convert from **RGB** to **HSV** and vice versa:

- [RGB to HSV](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.html)
- [HSV to RGB](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsv-to-rgb.html)

More info on **HSV**:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

**"All cats are gray in the dark"**

Implement a dynamic color range. Adjust the 'red' range based on the brightness and/or saturation of the current pixel. Put a weight scale (on how much they affect the range in %) on the saturation and brightness values to determine your range ... play around to achieve the best results.

Answer (score 0):

You used RGB, and HSV method, which it is good, and both are ok.

The problem is about defining red. Hue (or R) is not enough: it contains many other colours (in the broader sense): browns are dark/unsaturated reds (or oranges). Pink is also a tint of red (so red + white, so unsaturated).

So in your first method, I would add a condition: R > 127 (you must check yourself a good threshold). And possibly change the other conditions with a higher ratio of R to G and B and possibly adding  also the ration R to (G+B). The first new added condition is about reds (and not "dark reds/browns), and brightness. Your two conditions are about "hue" (hue is defined by the top two values), and the last condition I wrote is about saturation.

You can do in a similar way for HSV: filter H (as you did), but you must filter also  V (you want just bright reds), and also an high saturation, so you must filter all channels.

You should test yourself the saturation levels. The problem is that eyes adapt quickly to colours, so some images with a lot of redish colours are seen normally (less redish) by humans, but more red by above calculation. Etc. (so usually for such works there is some sliders to modify, e.v. you can try to automatize, but you need to find overall hue and brightness of image, and possibly complex methods, see CIECAM).